# failed to boxplot one figure in each canvas using Seaborn for groupby data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataset, which is as follows:

```
funding_round_type  variable    value
venture raised_amount_usd   7.0000000000
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.8450980400
venture raised_amount_usd   6.5323565818
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3010299957
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.6370892735
venture raised_amount_usd   5.8570253658
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.4771212547
venture raised_amount_usd   7.3010299957
venture raised_amount_usd   6.2304489214
venture raised_amount_usd   6.9493900066
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.1760912591
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.0000217142
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.6020599913
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   6.7781512504
venture raised_amount_usd   6.6989700043
venture raised_amount_usd   6.6020599913
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.6020599913
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.6020599913
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.6989700043
angel   raised_amount_usd   7.6427005481
venture raised_amount_usd   6.4014005408
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.1760912591
venture raised_amount_usd   5.4247836644
venture raised_amount_usd   6.4634199325
venture raised_amount_usd   6.1760912591
venture raised_amount_usd   5.8075350281
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.5910646070
venture raised_amount_usd   6.8197211705
venture raised_amount_usd   6.2397773156
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.1211296041
venture raised_amount_usd   6.2552725051
venture raised_amount_usd   6.9493900066
venture raised_amount_usd   7.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   6.4771212547
venture raised_amount_usd   6.4771212547
venture raised_amount_usd   6.1760912591
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.6720978579
venture raised_amount_usd   6.5477747054
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.8750612634
venture raised_amount_usd   5.6989700043
venture raised_amount_usd   7.5440680444
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.6989700043
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.0000000000
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.2041199827
angel   raised_amount_usd   5.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   7.7403626895
venture raised_amount_usd   5.7403626895
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.2920142616
venture raised_amount_usd   7.3010299957
venture raised_amount_usd   6.2552725051
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.9708116109
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.3979400087
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.2304489214
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.1461280357
angel   raised_amount_usd   5.6989700043
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.7403626895
venture raised_amount_usd   5.1768636160
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.6989700043
venture raised_amount_usd   6.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   7.1139433523
venture raised_amount_usd   6.7323937598
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.5784237281
venture raised_amount_usd   7.0791576125
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.1160628741
venture raised_amount_usd   6.2574520108
angel   raised_amount_usd   5.7920371044
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3802112417
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3979400087
venture raised_amount_usd   7.1760912591
venture raised_amount_usd   6.6989700043
venture raised_amount_usd   6.7118072290
venture raised_amount_usd   7.0934216852
venture raised_amount_usd   6.7781512504
venture raised_amount_usd   7.3010299957
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.8450980400
venture raised_amount_usd   6.4771212547
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3979400087
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.6989700043
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.3424226808
angel   raised_amount_usd   6.0000000000
angel   raised_amount_usd   5.3010299957
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.3010299957
venture raised_amount_usd   5.3009366123
angel   raised_amount_usd   4.6989700043
venture raised_amount_usd   7.2041199827
venture raised_amount_usd   7.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   7.1461280357
venture raised_amount_usd   6.6020599913
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.0969100130
venture raised_amount_usd   6.2011192509
venture raised_amount_usd   5.6803482066
venture raised_amount_usd   7.9157813085
venture raised_amount_usd   6.6989700043
venture raised_amount_usd   7.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   7.3010299957
venture raised_amount_usd   8.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   6.8450980400
venture raised_amount_usd   7.6020599913
venture raised_amount_usd   6.7944880467
venture raised_amount_usd   6.6989700043
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.3010299957
angel   raised_amount_usd   4.6020599913
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3979400087
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.6020599913
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.6989700043
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.2304489214
venture raised_amount_usd   6.1613680022
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.9542425094
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.3010299957
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   5.2125391607
venture raised_amount_usd   6.6020599913
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.3222192947
seed    raised_amount_usd   3.3010299957
venture raised_amount_usd   7.4771212547
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.6989700043
angel   raised_amount_usd   5.3455540773
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.9665265584
angel   raised_amount_usd   5.6503667852
venture raised_amount_usd   7.1760912591
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.3010299957
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.1335389084
venture raised_amount_usd   4.4771212547
venture raised_amount_usd   7.1760912591
venture raised_amount_usd   7.6232492904
angel   raised_amount_usd   5.8750612634
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3979400087
venture raised_amount_usd   5.6989700043
venture raised_amount_usd   6.0000000000
venture raised_amount_usd   6.2201080880
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.7634279936
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.3100323422
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3089940138
venture raised_amount_usd   5.1760912591
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3341345481
venture raised_amount_usd   7.4734869701
venture raised_amount_usd   6.9030899870
venture raised_amount_usd   7.4149733480
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3979400087
venture raised_amount_usd   6.8573324964
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.0599570200
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.5073835557
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.9030899870
seed    raised_amount_usd   5.0791812460
seed    raised_amount_usd   6.3222192947
venture raised_amount_usd   6.3010299957
venture raised_amount_usd   5.9030899870
seed    raised_amount_usd   4.6989700043
angel   raised_amount_usd   6.1655790462
venture raised_amount_usd   6.8041058192
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.5118833610
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   5.3025646833
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.9294189257
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.6989700043
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   6.6232492904
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.0000000000
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   6.5287849786
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   6.8450980400
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   5.5865648018
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   6.4771212547
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.8750612634
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.0000000000
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.0413926852
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.0638509231
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.9030899870
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.3010299957
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.3010299957
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   6.5326671293
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.8864887680
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.7403626895
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.0413926852
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.6253124510
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   8.3521825181
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.9364383376
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.6020599913
private_equity  raised_amount_usd   7.6532125138
```

I wanted to plot box plot for each `funding_round_type` in different canvas (of 2 x 2 frames i.e. 2 rows and 2 columns).

I was trying to use `seaborn` package for that purpose and my code looked something like this:

```
 fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=4)
 df.groupby('funding_round_type')['raised_amount_usd'].plot.box(subplots=True)
 plt.show()
```

It did not produce the result I was looking for.

Then I also tried:

```
 sns.regplot(x='funding_round_type', y='raised_amount_usd', data=df, ax=axs[0])
 sns.regplot(x='funding_round_type', y='raised_amount_usd', data=df, ax=axs[1])
 sns.boxplot(x='funding_round_type', y='raised_amount_usd', data=df, ax=axs[2])
 sns.boxplot(x='funding_round_type', y='raised_amount_usd', data=df, ax=axs[3])
```

This thrown me an error:

```
    ....
    .......
    2902         if tolerance is not None:
    KeyError: 'raised_amount_usd'
```

How can I get single boxplot for each `funding_round_type` in each frame of canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to create a boxplot for each subplot.

The code below supposes that you want different x-ranges for each of the boxes (otherwise you could simply put them together into one plot). Looping through each of the axes, the example code limits the x-axis to the interval between 5% and 95%, so outliers get cut away.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"funding_round_type": np.random.choice(["seed", "venture", "angel", "private_equity"], 50),
                   "value": np.random.normal(50, 10, 50)})

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="funding_round_type", col_wrap=2, sharex=False)
g.map(sns.boxplot, "value")
for col, ax in zip(g.col_names, g.axes.flat):
    ax.set_xlim(df[df["funding_round_type"] == col]["value"].quantile([0.05, 0.95]))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: facet grid with box plots]

To obtain vertical boxes, a problem is that these functions need a `x` parameter. A trick is to add a dummy column with an empty name and full of empty strings. Here is an example using `catplot`:

```py
df[""] = "" # create a dummy column to serve as x
g = sns.catplot(data=df, x="", y="value", col="funding_round_type", kind="box", col_wrap=2, sharey=False)
for col, ax in zip(g.col_names, g.axes.flat):
    ax.set_ylim(df[df["funding_round_type"] == col]["value"].quantile([0.05, 0.95]))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: catplot with boxes]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [`pandas.DataFrame.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html)?

This looks like the result you are asking for.

```
df.groupby('funding_round_type').boxplot(subplots=True, figsize=(6,6))
```

**Output**

[image: boxplot]

Comment: thanks. I tired it as well. but due to huge outliers, I was not getting boxplot at all. Is there a way to omit some 5% outliers (either side) and then use the above to plot?